# php цикл с таймером на замену файла

Tags: php, html, файлы

Есть 10 файлов, мне нужно перебрать их циклом с таймером на php, что бы раз в 1 час менялась ссылка на файл. Файлы лежат на сервере.

```
<a href="https://test.com" class="td_download_add"></a>
```

Цикл с перебором я сумею написать но как это связать со временем и потом всунуть в href не знаю.
Помогите с проблемой пожалуйста.

Comment: Пишешь список ссылок. Получаешь time(), вытаскиваешь из него часы. По результату выбираешь ссылку. Как вставить переменную РНР в ссылку - гугл знает.

Comment: может таки менять ссылку надо, а файлы не трогать?

Comment: да я имею в веду ссылку.